# how to get dynamically created radibuttonlist's count with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

How do you get the count of dynamically created Asp.Net Radiobuttonlist's count ?

here is my radiobuttonlist

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_poll" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I tried this but didnt work

```
if ($("#<%=rbl_poll.clientId %>").length == 0) {
   $("#div_poll_box").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

You can use class(class="rbl_poll") insread of id(ID="rbl_poll")

```
<asp:RadioButtonList class="rbl_poll" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And change script

```
if ($(".rbl_poll").length == 0) {
   $("#div_poll_box").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the radio button items in the list:

```
if ($("#rbl_poll input:radio").length == 0) {
   $("#div_poll_box").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#rbl_poll").length` *should* always be 1 since there *should* only be one element with the **unique** id `rbl_poll`.

You need to instead select the [*descendent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) elements inside the `id="rbl_poll"` element, for example with

```
if ($('#rbl_poll input[type="radio"]') === 0) {
    $('#div_poll_box').hide();
}
```